# Spring Batch Drive Query Example

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing, multirow

I am new to SpringBatch and I have searched high and low for an example for **Drive Query** based batch processing. I haven't been able to find one. I am looking to read from a database with a drive query so I can just query based on the primary key and then use the result to identify details for the ID and write to multiple tables. Has anyone done this or have a sample to refer to? TIA

Comment: You can find a complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72243842/5019386.